# String Extension improvement

Tags: c#, .net, strings, recursion

I am creating a string extension to validate some input.

My scenario is when we have a string it will format it according to following guideline.
If the sample string is “One Two Three Four Five” and the length is <=20 return same. If more than 20 then “One Two Three F Five”. If still length is more than 20 the “One Two T  F Five” etc...

Is there any way I can improve this code? I thought it can use recursion?

```
public static string ToShortName(this string name)
        {
            if (name.Length <= 20) return name;

            var namelist = name.Split(' ');

            var length = name.Length;

            //add spaces
            length = length + namelist.Count() - 1;

            var output = "";
            var indexList = new List<int>();
            for (var i = namelist.Count() - 2; i >=1 ; i--)
            {
                indexList.Add(i);
                if (length - namelist[i].Length <= 20)
                {
                    break;
                }
                length = length - namelist[i].Length;
            }

            foreach (var i in indexList)
            {
                namelist[i] = namelist[i].Substring(0, 1);
            }
            output = string.Join(" ", namelist);

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: As a side note, I would expect "validation" to return a true/false (or valid/invalid), rather than to return a possibly modified string. You may want to call this something else.

Comment: What should happen when you shorten is as much as you can and it still isn't less than 20 characters?

Comment: @svick: This is coming from a field which will be maximum 70 characters

Comment: @developcode It's still possible that can't be shortened, if the last and first words are too long, or if there's too many short words in the middle.

Comment: @svick: That's the same thing I raised for Henriks' answer as well. It should have a check before it return the result. May be to return the initials only if the `result>20`. (I believe no one will have name initial which can occupy 20 characters though:))

Comment: @MichaelUrman: Yes thanks, I have changed the name of the method

Comment: @developcode: That's a much better name than before!

Answer (score 2):

You should remove this

```
length = length + namelist.Count() - 1;
```

because length already includes the spaces.

This

```
length = length - namelist[i].Length;
```

should be

```
length -= namelist[i].Length - 1;
```

because `namelist[i].Length-1` is the number of characters that are removed.

Also: why `i >=1 - 1` instead of `i >= 0`?

You can also do it in a single loop like this:

```
        for (var i = namelist.Count() - 2; i >=1 && length > 20; i--)
        {
            length -= namelist[i].Length - 1;
            namelist[i] = namelist[i].Substring(0, 1);
        }

        return string.Join(" ", namelist);
```

Comment: Sorry,i >=1 - 1 was mistake. it is i >=1

Comment: I am running two loops at the moment. Is it a good way of doing?

Comment: @developcode You can use single loop. See my edit.

Comment: @Henrik: This loop will make everything shorter. like `O T T F Five`

Comment: @huMptyduMpty No. Did you miss the `&& length > 20`?

Comment: @Henrik: Of course. I did miss that!! This is all fine :)

Comment: @Henrik: But at the end its better to check `if (output.Length > 39)
                    output = output.NameCorrection();`?? but to check the first and last.since this always ignoring the first and last words. If combination of these to can be longer than 20 this will be invalid I guess?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string StringCorrection(this string name)
```

`StringCorrection()` is not a great name. 1. I don't see any reason to call out the `String` type in the name. 2. This is not really a correction, it's more like shortening.

Also, I'm not sure that this should be an extension method, because it's something quite specific, it's not generally useful for almost any string.

```
if (name.Length <= 20) return name;
```

I think the max length should be a parameter with a default value, so that the method is more general. Even if you don't do that, at least don't repeat the value, use a variable for it.

```
var output = "";
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to declare the variable this early, or to actually have the variable at all. You could just write:

```
return string.Join(" ", namelist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is more concise implementation. Also, when length of the string is more than max length, we need to run the loop at least once, so we should use **do..while** here.

```
public static string StringCorrection(this string name)
{
    int maxLength = 20;
    if (name.Length <= maxLength) return name;

    string[] nameArray = name.Split(' ');
    int extraLength = name.Length - maxLength;
    int currentIndex = nameArray.Length - 2;

    if (currentIndex <= 0) return name;

    int wordLength = 0;
    do
    {
        wordLength = nameArray[currentIndex].Length;
        nameArray[currentIndex] = nameArray[currentIndex].Substring(0, 1);
        extraLength -= (--wordLength);
        currentIndex--;
    } while (extraLength > 0 && currentIndex > 0);

    return string.Join(" ", nameArray);
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to suggest using a do-while loop, and your implementation will walk right off the array if the described task isn't possible. But otherwise the advice is spot on.

Comment: Yes, we can add condition to make sure loop doesn't run off the array. I have updated the loop condition to care of that.